# useEffect and a busy thread

Tags: reactjs, multithreading, react-hooks, use-effect

Here is a React component with a **Heavy Calculation** inside it.

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { SetLoading } from "./action";
import { Context } from "./context";
import { doPointlessComputationsWithBlocking } from "./calculation";

const Heavy = (props) => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Context);

  useEffect(() => {
    SetLoading(dispatch, true);
    console.log("[start]");

    doPointlessComputationsWithBlocking();

    SetLoading(dispatch, false);
    console.log("[end]");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>When I am busy, you should see Calculating... in the next line</div>
  );
};

export default Heavy;
```

I expected to see the `[end]` after `[start]` and some delay. But what happens is that `useEffect` executes the code on its first run and log everything together after `doPointlessComputationsWithBlocking` is done.

[Here is a link to the code](https://o0dhj.csb.app/)

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: console.log() is not logging anything until the whole code execution is done.

Answer (score 0):

Add timestamps to your console.logs and you will see, that [start] executes a long before calculation is done. So your argument, that it runs all after calculation, is wrong.

Just add:

```
console.log("[start]", new Date().getTime());

console.log(primes, new Date().getTime());

console.log("[end]", new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: The main problem is that the delay in execution is not reflected in the state. I dispatched before and after the thread-blocking function and the state only **shows** changes after the whole execution not during it.